# Data points not showing in line chart

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-charts

I'm using iOS-Charts library to make charts in my project. I tried to plot some reading against dateTime stamp. I converted the date object to milliseconds in order to make it as a double value which the line chart accepts. When I tried this method blank graph appears with labels and without any data points. That is shown in below screenshot.
[image]

When I printed those data points using print() function I got the following.

```
ChartDataEntry, x: 1453871669.0, y 24.54
ChartDataEntry, x: 1453869902.0, y 24.84
ChartDataEntry, x: 1453869846.0, y 24.84
```

I doubt that it's because the x value too hight no point appears. If my doubt right please provide a solution to rectify this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we get the chart library link?

Comment: @Poles https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: The X&Y values are coming like this or this is the converted one??

Comment: your x is x: 1453871669 . Where you accept to plot it in this range?

Comment: @Poles that is converted one

Comment: @Sofeda than how do I plot timestamp without converting it to milliseconds.

Comment: @PraveenKumar : you need to convert X & Y value to screen's X & Y coordinates. And your X & Y value doesn't seem a CGPoint of screen.

Comment: i see your x is 0 and your data value of x is x: 1453871669. so this value will be plot on x = 0?! may be  i am missing something.

Answer (score 6):

Nice to meet you my friend, cause I meet the same problem as well.

```
ChartDataEntry, x: 1453871669.0, y 24.54
ChartDataEntry, x: 1453869902.0, y 24.84
ChartDataEntry, x: 1453869846.0, y 24.84
```

Looks like your data are in a descending order right? Unfortunately that is the problem.If you sort them in a ascending order,I think you can see them all.

Maybe it's a bug of Charts.

Comment: yes this is the solution. Data is only accepted if it is in sorted order... this should really be made clear in the documentation... it took me so long to find this.